# Drupal - drush installation on mamp server

Tags: drupal, mamp, drush

I have a drupal project, and I am trying to install drush for mamp server. I have run:

`composer global require drush/drush:dev-master`

In the directory of my project, but when I am trying to run:

```
drush status
```

I get:

```
command not found: drush
```

Comment: use composer install command

Answer (score 0):

Follow information listed in : https://www.drupal.org/node/1674222

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you definitely did not carry these two steps out correctly, which symlink the "drush" binary.

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s /Users/myusername/drush/drush
```

Replace /Users/myusername/ with the name of the directory where you unpacked Drush.

You may need to quit and restart Terminal after completing these instructions before running any drush commands.

http://youtu.be/TCg02d4am_Q for more details

If you're still having problems, I suggest following the instructions here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1674222 and reporting back, editting your answer to reflect the new error you get, so we can actually help you figure out what step of the install you're not running successfully.